# Django composite primary key for a friendship table without using User

Tags: django, database, django-models

I have done this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

class Following(models.Model):
    following_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    person_id = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='child')
    follower_id = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='father')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("person_id", "follower_id"),)
```

I will get error if I don't set Null=True in foreign keys, if I set it to True then it creates a Following table like this:

```
id   person_id   follower_id
1     Null           2
10    Null           1
```

This is the way that I add data to it:

```
Following(Person.objects.get(pk=1).id, Person.objects.get(pk=2).id)
```

I just want to have a composite PK out of both FKs. It makes the first item as PK, second item as FK follower_id and Null for person_id. Is there any way to make it like this:

```
id   person_id   follower_id
1     1           2
2    10           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/),

The Model class only accepts keyword args.

```
class Model(**kwargs)
```

Where the keyword arguments are simply the names of the fields you’ve defined on your model.

Accordingly you need to modify your object save line to:

```
f = Following(person=Person.objects.get(pk=1), follower=Person.objects.get(pk=2))
f.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, only to mention that the .id at the end should be removed since the item must be Person instance. It would be better to modify for others to use it in the future.